# Why when i close the control the Form1 is not back to the CenterScreen position?

Tags: c#

```
private void histogramGraphsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            HistogramGraphs1 = new Lightnings_Extractor.Histogram_Graphs();
            HistogramGraphs1.Show();
            HistogramGraphs1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(HistogramGraphs1_FormClosing);
            histogramGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;

        }



private void HistogramGraphs1_FormClosing(object sender , FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        histogramGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
```

First time i put the Form in position 0,0
then on the Closing event i want it to back to the center screen but the Form is still in 0,0 position.

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prevent to close this form by set `e.Cancel = true`. then move window to center of screen:

```
private void HistogramGraphs1_FormClosing(object sender , FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    histogramGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    e.Cancel = true;
    int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - this.Width / 2;
    int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2 - this.Height / 2;
    this.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

and this MSDN article may be useful:

- [Setting the Screen Location of Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

explain:

> [**`CancelEventArgs.Cancel`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx): Gets or sets a value indicating whether the event should be canceled.
>
> [**`Form.Location Property`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414%28v=VS.80%29.aspx): Gets or sets the Point that represents the upper-left corner of the Form in screen coordinates.

Comment: Ria your code is working just i had to remove the line: e.Cancel = true; If im using it it will prevent me from closing the Control the ZedGraph. I wanted to close it but also move the Form1 to the center of the screen.  HistogramGraphs1 is a new Form that contain the ZedGraph control.

Answer (score 0):

if your setting the this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; then you need to re-open the form. Other wise it will not effect.